# Converting CompletableFuture<Optional<Class>> to Class

Tags: java

i have an User Class and i want to retreive from CompletableFuture<Optional>

```
        CompletableFuture<Optional<User>> userCache = plugin.getBPApi().getUser(player.getUniqueId());
        User user = userCache.get();
        return String.valueOf(user.getTier());
```

But when i compile it throws the following error:

> java.util.Optional<io.github.battlepass.objects.user.User> cannot be converted to io.github.battlepass.objects.user.User

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`userCache.get()` doesn't return a `User`, but a `Optional` which contains a user.

Optional is useful for handling values that could be null, so you should implement some logic that will handle this case

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = userCache.get();
return optionalUser.map(user -> String.valueOf(user.getTier())).orElse("");
```

In this example we map the `Optional<User>` to a `Optional<String>` and if no value is present return a empty string.

Comment: Well, unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown